# MySQL order by sub-select result

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by

I want to dynamically order a dataset with a sub-select query after the order by clause. To get myself familiar with this I created a small test set and tried various things from which neither worked.

To directly see the result I try to produce an error by ordering by a column that does not exist. This is my query and the result:

```
select * from entries order by 2 desc, (select case when (1=1) then 4 else 5 end);
select * from entries order by 2 desc, (select if(1=1,4,5));
+----+------+---------+------+
| id | name | content | time |
+----+------+---------+------+
| 19 | ccc  | ccc     |  300 |
| 18 | bbb  | bbb     |  200 |
| 17 | aaa  | aaa     |  100 |
| 20 | aaa  | aaa     |  400 |
| 21 | aaa  | aaa     |   50 |
+----+------+---------+------+
```

Switching from 1=1 to 1=2 does not alter the result in any way.  I expected an error with 1=2 but nothing happened. Even in this form both queries should order be the 4th column, which they dont.

I expect that the dataset is ordered by the forth column so it would look like this:

```
+----+------+---------+------+
| id | name | content | time |
+----+------+---------+------+
| 19 | ccc  | ccc     |  300 |
| 18 | bbb  | bbb     |  200 |
| 21 | aaa  | aaa     |   50 |
| 17 | aaa  | aaa     |  100 |
| 20 | aaa  | aaa     |  400 |
+----+------+---------+------+
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You want to sort by the fifth column, but there are only four. What is that fifth column you have in mind?

Comment: Your example doesn't help much. It's simply `order by 2 desc, 4` or `order by id desc, time`.

Comment: I need it to work with order by 2 desc, 4 but the 4 is the result of the case when... part.

Comment: The `case when` results in the value 4 for every row, so it doesn't influence the order.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use the positional syntax for `order by` -- I even think it is deprecated in the ANSI standard.  An integer -- by itself -- represents a column by position.  However, in expressions with numbers, the values are, well, just numbers.

So, include the column names explicitly:

```
order by name desc,
         (case when (1=1) then time else ?? end)
```

There is no reason to have `select` before the `case`.

Comment: I know that the positional syntax is not nice, but in my contect I have no other option. With the column name it sort of works. Unfortunatly I get an error if I use an unknown column name. I thereby assume that both alternatives must be present in the given table?

Comment: In the `case` statement, numbers are numbers not column positions.